# How to avoid source code duplication in two static libraries which A depends on B?

Tags: ios, static-libraries

Form my project wise, I need to build two iOS static frameworks:

- A libA which provide basic functionalities and,
- A libB which contains extensional functionality but depends on the
  basic functions provided by libA.

Such as:

In libA:

```
void foo {...}
```

In libB:

```
void bar { foo(); ... }
```

Now the source code of `foo()` is existing in both libA and libB. If there's an executable link with libA and libB simultaneously and, it calls both the `foo()` and `bar()`, then there will be two copies of the source code of `foo()` inside of the executable. Also, there will be many similar cases between these two libs. So eventually the executable size is unnecessarily bigger than needed.

Is there's a way to make the implementation of `foo()` only existing in libA, But not in libB? Kinda like the forward declarations, when I build the libB, that I only need to depend on the declarations but no need to link with the actual implementations? Then the executable eventually can avoid duplicated copies of `foo()` in its code space.

I can't find any related LLVM guidance for this, probably I've used the irrelevant keywords. Will be really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code for foo should not be in libB unless some sort of inlining or templates were done and in the case of templates the code should be deduplicated when linked by functionality of the linker.  Are you sure this is actually happening?

Step 1 is checking if your have a performance problem with what you’re optimizing, if not, don’t spend your time there.

If you’re actually having a performance problem there the compiler shouldn’t be duplicating code unless it has visibility in to both functions in which case it follows its inlining rules which you probably don’t want to tweak unless you’re a specialized embedded developer or a compiler engineer. Inlining rules are incredibly complex and messing with them is almost always wrong.

Comment: Mmm... I don't have directly proof, however I do see whatever functionality provided by `foo` can be used when I call `bar` if I only link libB in an executable. Isn't that mean the implementation of `foo` already existed in libB?